# 500 status code for symfony functional test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm performing a test just to see if a certain route is working. The page/route is found at http://localhost/login and when I go there in the browser it works fine and I've tested this with no cookies and my cache cleared.

However, as soon as I test it in the phpunit `LoginControllerTest` class I recieve a 500 status code internal server error.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class LoginControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testLoginPage()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login'); 
        // var_dump($client->getRequest()->getContent()); // Is empty
        // 200 => 'OK'
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
    // ...
```

And so running `phpunit` fails with:

```
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

---

Here is the `security.yml` in case that is of any use in understanding the problem.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Users
                property: Username

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~   

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            pattern: ^/manage
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/manage, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The route is defined and working (as expected).

```
// ...
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="LoginForm")
     */
    public function loginFormAction(Request $request)
    {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 500 error can be caused by anything in your case.

What you could do in such situation is to dump the content of the response and check the Symfony debugging message.

I usually use such code snippet for quick checking such errors directly in terminal:

```
if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
    $block = $crawler->filter('div.text_exception > h1');
    if ($block->count()) {
        $error = $block->text();
    }
}
```

where `div.text_exception > h1` is the xpath from Symfony2 debug page to the message itself

Then just print the `$error`

Comment: Thanks for stepping me in the right direction. I've been looking through the output of the response and have used your code to print the error in the terminal. I have found using ```$crawler->filter('title');``` gives a nice friendly error message - the xpath you gave doesn't actually exist for the response I get. I should be able to fix the errors now.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit old, but it's possible (at least since symfony 5.2) to do

```
$client->catchExceptions(false);
```

And you will get the stack trace directly in phpunit output

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't what @op needed but it really helped me.